# Matching remitter and receiver of transaction based on two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There are two dataframes. The first one shows money transfers from certain `clients`. The second datatframe shows which `clients` receive those money. `df1` has only senders' id's, `df2` has only receivers'. I need to add to each dataframe a column that show the other end of the transaction, based on `date and time` and `group_id` (only clients in one group can tranfer money to each other). The trick is that money sent few minutes before received, so there are no exact matches on `date` columns in `df1` and `df2`. Another thing is that one `client` can send money to two or more different `clients` in his `group`, so there might not be exact match in `price` columns as well (`price` in `df1` is always equal or higher than in `df2`).
Is there away to add column to `df2` that shows from which `client` the money came from using data in `df1`? Is it possible to add to `df1` `client_id` to which the money were sent based on data in `df2`, considering that there may be multiple receivers which should result in adding additional fields?
Examples of initial dataframes:

df1

```
client_id group_id date_payed             price_payed
7         11       01.01.2019  14:41:37   16500
8         14       05.01.2019  14:40:00   15000
9         18       08.01.2019  12:13:04   14000
```

df2

```
client_id group_id date_received          price_received
1         11       01.01.2019  14:44:37   10000
2         11       01.01.2019  14:44:37   6500
3         14       05.01.2019  14:42:00   12000
4         14       05.01.2019  14:42:00   3000
5         18       08.01.2019  12:16:04   14000
```

In this example we need to match sender #7 with receiver #1 and 2, #8 with #3 and 4, #9 with #5.

Comment: Do you just want something like: `df1.merge(df2, on='group_id')`? Or maybe: `df2['group_id'].map(df1.set_index('group_id')['client_id'])`

Comment: That would work for this example, but there might be more than one sender in the group. In this case match on date and price is also required

Comment: Then merge on all 3?

Comment: That would work if not for two factors: `date_payed` and `date_received` are few minutes apart (the exact number of minutes could vary); there is no exact match in `price` as well: for example `client` 7 sends 16500, but `client` 1 received 10000 and `client` 2 received 6500

Comment: Then you aren't representing your problem well.  Please review [ask] and create a [mcve] that accurately demonstrates your *actual* problem.  You should also include your current attempt so it's obvious what you've tried.